# Android Studio Facebook Login crash on startup

Tags: android

I have just been following the guide here ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2#step1 ) trying to make FB login work. Seems to me that I was doing well until step (2: Authentication change triggers) as then, the app crashes on launch, if I use default layout it launches, but with the layout specified in the guide the application crashes. I can see the facebook button for a small moment and then the application crashes. Can`t seem to find any help on the web, any help would be much apreciated.

Manifest-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.ritu5" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.internet"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.ritu5.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId "
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity-

```
package com.mycompany.ritu5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}





}
```

layout>main-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainFragment-

```
package com.mycompany.ritu5;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Post the crash logCat

Answer (score 0):

You have one additional space in meta-data:
android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId "

Correct with:
android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"

I made the same silly mistake a few days ago.